# How can I call a Lua script from Java

Tags: java, lua

I want to run a Lua script from Java GUI. Can I develop it in a `Java IDE`. What I want to achieve:

1. I will have a button in Java that will run a Lua script.
2. Then the Lua script will run and return something that I can capture in my Java code and show it in the GUI of java.

Answer (score 3):

I found a [package](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html), which helps in integration of Lua with Java.

Simple Application:

```
import org.luaj.vm2.*;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.*;

Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
LuaValue chunk = globals.loadfile("examples/lua/hello.lua");
chunk.call();
```

On doing chuck.call(), save the return value to a variable. See, if that helps.

Comment: when is inside the chunk.call()  thought it is returning me the line string "hello world" ??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood what you're saying.

Comment: can i run any linux terminal command using this and get the result?? like 'ls' using luaj

Comment: @setubasak I am not sure about that, coz loadfile basically load lua file and is been executed by doing call().